# Members of equivalence classes in $Z(p^\infty)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $Z(p^\infty)$ be the following subset of the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$:
>   $$Z(p^\infty)=\{\overline{a/b}\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } b=p^i \text{ for some } i\geq0\}.$$

I am not sure if this is worth my time trying to show but I was wondering how I can be sure that if I pick some $\frac{c}{d} \in \overline{\frac{a}{p^i}}$ that $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{m}{p^k}$ for $k\geq 0$.

Pick $\overline{\frac{a}{p^i}} \in Z(p^\infty)$ and assume that $\frac{a}{p^i}$ is in reduced form. Let $\frac{c}{d} \in \overline{\frac{a}{p^i}}$ with reduced form. I want $d=p^k$ for some $k\geq0$. If $i=0$, it is easy. Suppose $i>0$. As $\frac{c}{d} \in \overline{\frac{a}{p^i}}$,
$$\frac{c}{d} \sim \frac{a}{p^i} \Leftrightarrow \frac{a}{p^i}-\frac{c}{d} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow p^i \mid (ad-cp^i).$$
$$\frac{a}{p^i}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad-cp^i}{dp^i}$$
and so $p^i\mid (ad-cp^i)$ which means $\mathbb{Z} \ni \frac{ad-cp^i}{p^i}=\frac{ad}{p^i}-c \Rightarrow p^i \mid ad$ but as $\frac{a}{p^i}$ is in reduced form, $\gcd(a,p^i)=1$ and so $p^i \mid d$. At this point, I tried to do something with $\mathrm{lcm}(c,d)=cd$ and show $d \mid p^i$ but I'm not having any success there. Any advice at this point or alternate solutions?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The elements of a coset $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$ are all of the form $\displaystyle \frac{a}{p^n}+d=\frac{p^n d+a}{p^n}$.

Comment: Hint: Adding an integer to a fraction does not change what primes occur in the denominator. (But well spotted that this is something that one should prove for the definition to be ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different approch for this last part of the solution. You have proved that $p^i \mid d$.

Since $\frac{ad-cp^i}{p^id}  \in \mathbb Z$ you also have that $d \mid ad - cp^i$ and so $d \mid cp^i$. By hypothesis $\gcd(d,c)=1$ (you have taken $\frac{c}{d}$ in reduced form) this implies that $d \mid p^i$. From what just proved we have to conclude that $d=p^i$.

Comment: This is appreciated and I guess the clear way to go given the way that I went.